# Css blocks draw area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m trying to get an website work, here the user can draw something.
Besides this, the user can swipe between three screens.
But somehow the css of the swipe-container blockades my draw function. The html structure looks like this:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper" style="lalal">

<div class="swiper-slide red-slide"> </div>

<div class="swiper-slide blue-slide" style="width: 1366px;"> </div>

<div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">

    <div id="areaDraw"><canvas width="450" height="187"></canvas><canvas width="450"  height="187" style="display: block;"></canvas><canvas width="450" height="187"></canvas>        </div>

<input type="text" name="canvascontent" id="canvascontent">
 <input type="button" onclick="sketch.redrawAnimate()" style="" value="Animate">
 <input type="button" onclick="alert(sketch.toDataURL())" style="" value="Redraw">
.....
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So actually my website works when i simply remove the first div with the class="swiper-container" like you can see here:
[Working example](http://illahabibi.webege.com/Hulwith.html)

But with the first div and class="siwper-container" the draw area wont work, like you can see here:
[Not working example](http://illahabibi.webege.com/Hul.html)

My guess is that the css of the swiper container blocks the function of the draw area:

```
.swiper-container {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
-o-backface-visibility:hidden;
 backface-visibility:hidden;
 /* Fix of Webkit flickering */
z-index:1;
}

.swiper-container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}
```

I really dont know how to fix this!

The two links i gave you earlier in this post contain the whole css files. Also i have to add that only the yellow section on the pages work as draw area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orange-slide` (drawing area) is hidden behind `swiper-container`.

To see it you can:

add this

```
.orange-slide {
    position: absolute;
}
```

or remove this

```
.swiper-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Btw: in `areaDraw` you have 3 `canvas` and probably javascript create 2 `canvas` more. Are you need so much `canvas` in the same place ? Well, not exactly in the same place. It seems I draw on one canvas and script redraws it on another canvas laying not exacly in the same place so picture moves to the left.

I had to add:

```
canvas {
    left: 0;
}
```